# Using gradient vector to find curve on plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have this problem:

The temperature $T$ in a square region of the $(x,y)$ plane is given by the formula:
$$T(,)=^3−+11$$ for $$,∈(−2,2).$$

An ant inside the square region is initially at the point $(1,\frac{1}{3})$.

What is the equation of the curve the ant should move along in order to ensure that the temperature it experiences decreases as rapidly as possible?

So far I have gotten the partial differentials:

$$ f_x=-1, f_y=3y^2$$

So the gradient vector at any point $(x,y)$ has the vector equation $(-1 , 3y^2)$. But then to follow the steepest descent we should go away from the gradient vector in the opposite vector so $(1,-3y^2)$.

But then I am not sure where to go next to find the equation of the curve?

Is it a function with $f(1)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $f'(x)=-3y^2$

I am quite confused, wondering if anyone could shed any light on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to solve the problem parametricaly. Write the trajectory of the ant as
$$
\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))
$$
Then to have the stepest descent in temperature we must have
$$
\gamma'(t)=-\nabla T(\gamma(t))
$$
In coordinates this reads
$$
x'(t)=1/3,\quad y'(t)=-3y^2(t)
$$
You can integrate this equation, using the initial condition to get
$$
x(t)=t/3+1, \quad \frac{1}{y(t)}-\frac{1}{1/3}=3t\Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{3y(t)}-1
$$
and you get the equation by replacing $t$ in the $x$ equation
$$
x=\frac{1}{9y}+2/3
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

So at the beginning the ant will move a $d {\bf s} = -\nabla T({\bf s}_0)v dt$

Comment: Ahhh thank you!